# What is the "fourth" Halo 4 ordnance slot?

Tags: halo-4

I spotted this in a recent Halo 4 video:
[image]

The player has just got their ordnance drop, which consists of a Rocket Launcher, a Railgun, and an overshield. There's also the "two arrow" icon at the top - what is this? Is this a new ability that gets unlocked at rank 50, when you reach a specialization, or just a "random" button that chooses one of the 3 for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a side effect of the ["Requisition" armor mod](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Requisition), which allows you to re-roll your selections from an ordnance drop.  It is part of the [Tracker](http://www.ign.com/wikis/halo-4/Tracker) specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you have to complete the Tracker specialisattion to Lvl TRACKER-10 and then equip it. You get a whole new choice of another three ordnance drops, however you cannot reverse the choice
(eg go back to the original 3)